# How to make IntelliJ comments with the '|' symbol?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am not sure if they are comments and if it's only for IntelliJ, but I want to know that. Also, how to make them? Why would I use them instead of classic comments?

[image]

The source code was from an Instagram page featuring Kotlin posts and I wanted to know more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [Render Javadocs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html#toggle-rendered-view) feature.

[image: render]

Comment: So that is how we can use comments like "/** */" properly! I'll definitely use that in the future as well. Thanks for sharing the information!